# Симуляция физики веревки / провода / цепи в Unity. Чем делается?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-faq

Мне нужно сделать симуляцию проводов со своей физикой в Unity, но не знаю при помощи какого инструмента это делать. Подскажете?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть такая штука как Joint. Всегда актуальная документация по джоинтам есть в документации к юнити: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html . Если это 2д проэкт, то там есть отдельно 2dJoint-ы: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints2D.html

Через него, например, реализуется таскание при помощи веревок/цепей/проводов. У документации юнити [видеотуториал по использованию джоинтов](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-joints).

[А вот здесь можно найти неофициальный туториал, только для создания физики таскания на веревке при помощи джоинтов](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4YCj4Tid0w).

Формально, твоя задача сделать несколько секций цилиндров соединенных между собой при помощи джоинтов и у тебя будет веревка/цепь/провод. Чем больше количество секций - тем реалистичнее выйдет.

---

Еще можешь в принципе погуглить что-то вроде "unity rope physics" и, возможно, получишь другие варианты решений. Но, скорее всего, получишь все то же решение через Joint.

Comment: Кто ставят минусы, вы хоть отпишитесь почему ставите

Comment: Ссылки - это не ответ, "соедините парочку Joint'ов" - это не пояснение, имхо, точнее, место ему в комментариях, а не в ответах. Как этот вопрос помог автору, раз он его правильным отметил, я не знаю, но **лично я** в нем пользы не вижу, просто загуглить можно и без промежуточной помощи стэка.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Почему не ответ? Был вопрос "каким инструментом делается?"... Даже не так, я процитирую: `Мне нужно сделать симуляцию проводов со своей физикой в Unity, но не знаю при помощи какого инструмента это делать.` Что сделал я? Я ответил: "Joint-ами" :) Даже ответил значительно шире чем вопрос спрашивал. То есть я мог, даже, ссылок не приводить в ответ. Я мог ответить вообще одним словом и это был бы ответ на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, ответ который был дан полностью мне помог. Я думаю не важно как отвечает пользователь, главное чтобы тот кто задаёт вопрос понял и принял.

Comment: @АлексейБобрович, хорошо, в таком случае ответ выглядит справедливо, убрал минус

Comment: @Andrew, и тем не менее я не согласен с меткой `unity3d-faq`, этот вопрос сложно назвать "популярным"

Answer (score 4):

Я знаю одну неплохую реализацию, насколько мне известно её нет в AssetStore, однако она есть на [github](https://github.com/NoxWings/Cable-Component).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение как раз полностью отвязано от физики в unity что является одновременно и плюсом и минусом. С одной стороны коллизии не обсчитываются вообще, однако все решения на основе физики unity были мягко говоря не очень, как раз из-за странностей обработки коллизий со звеньями цепи в веревке на joint-ах. И еще кабель рендерится сам по-себе и не участвует в Global Illumination, т.е. не отбрасывает и не принимает тени и свет

Comment: Этот вариант мне конечно подходит, но так я пока начинающий, я предпочту Joints.