# Как реализовать выстрел из гарпуна(хука)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу реализовать выстрел из гарпуна(хука), как в игре **Dota 2**.
Чтобы когда Pudge бросал крюк:
1. За крюком следовала линия (тросс)
2. При возвращении хука - тросс сокращался и потом вовсе исчезал.
Вот видео - https://youtu.be/xlcw7VGaqiY

1 пункт примерно понимаю как реализовать, а вот со вторым возникают большие трудности.
Есть какие-нибудь идеи как можно такое реализовать? Желательно бы со ссылочками

Comment: Покажите, как вы 1 пункт реализовали

Comment: у меня есть 2 варианта: первый - это через trail renderer, второй - через line renderer

Comment: А должны ли другие обьекты как-бы то ни было взаимодействовать с веревкой на уровне физики? Или можно что бы персонажи могли проходить сквозь веревку? Если да, то лайн рендерер точно не покатит. А трейл может покатить если попробовать на трейл нацепить меш коллайдер.

Comment: нет, взаимодействие веревки не должно быть ни с чем, это просто визуал, никакой физики и взаимодействия с окружающим миром

Comment: на счет трейла и меш коллайдера можно подробнее?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/957624/188366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению Joint'ы мне не помогли, но помог Line Renderer. Я просто нацепил на каждый объект хука `line renderer` и в качестве стартовой позиции линии я указывал игрока, а в качестве конечной - `transform.position` самого хука.

Comment: только вот на лайн-рендерер ты не нацепишь обьекты или текстуры. Ну, допустим обьект цепи. А вот на сплайн уже это сделать возможно :)

Comment: почему? можно же на лайн рендерер нацепить текстуры, т.е создаешь материал с текстурами и прикрепляешь их к рендеру

Comment: А, да, текстуру можно и вправду. А вот 3дшные обьекты вдоль уже нельзя без костылей)

Answer (score 4):

Есть такая штука как Joint. 
Всегда актуальная документация по джоинтам есть в документации к юнити: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html .

Если это 2д проэкт, то там есть отдельно 2dJoint-ы: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints2D.html

Через него, например, реализуется таскание при помощи веревок/цепей/проводов. У документации юнити [видеотуториал по использованию джоинтов](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-joints).

[А вот здесь можно найти неофициальный туториал, только для создания физики таскания на веревке при помощи джоинтов](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4YCj4Tid0w).

Формально, твоя задача сделать несколько секций цилиндров соединенных между собой при помощи джоинтов и у тебя будет веревка/цепь/провод. Чем больше количество секций - тем реалистичнее выйдет.

Думаю, что если заскейлить размер веревки по нужной оси(Relative только!) то получится именно тот эфект, который нужно и на основе физики будет притягиватся персонаж.

Думаю что это решение подойдет если нужна физическая составляющая.

---

Так же есть решение через https://github.com/NoxWings/Cable-Component

Здесь физика веревки не будет учитыватся. Немного более широкое описание: [Unity Cable-Component](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/957624/188366)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В даном случае т.к. веревка нефизическая, нужно будет при прикреплении к персонажу/предмету подсовывать его... Можно попробовать двигать через MoveToward(), но я не уверен на сколько это красивое решение...

---

UPD:

Есть еще третий вариант. Думаю, по быстродействию он будет самым оптимальным:

Нарисовать между центрами двух обьектов сплайн, а потом вдоль сплайна рисовать звенья веревки/цепи. Как это сделать можно почитать, например, вот здесь: https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/

Сплайн должен быть двухточечным. Т.е. указыватся начало и конец -- без промежуточных точек. Обновлять позиции точек будет достаточно просто...

Думаю, на том видео которое было примером был взят именно этот путь реализации.

Comment: О, моя гифка =)